# What is the original of the Saadat Hasan Manto short story translated as "Rude"?

Tags: short-stories, translation, urdu-language, saadat-hasan-manto

I have been reading Saadat Hasan Manto's *Bombay Stories*, a compilation translated from the Urdu by Matt Reeck and Aftab Ahmad (2012; New York: Vintage, 2014). Alongside the English translations, I've been reading the versions translated into Hindi (or transliterated into Devanagari; for the most part, Urdu and Hindi differ only in script, so translation is largely a matter of transliteration) at [Rekhta](https://www.rekhta.org/authors/saadat-hasan-manto/stories?lang=hi). However, I've been unable to track down the original of one of the stories in the collection. Its title is given as "Rude," and it is on pp. 126–136 of the volume. The translation begins:

> When I left Delhi to return to Bombay, I was upset because it meant parting with good friends and a job my wife approved of—stable, easy work that netted us 250 rupees on the first of each month. Nevertheless I was suddenly overcome by a desire to leave, and not even my wife's crying and carrying on could dissuade me.

The story is largely about the friendship between the narrator's wife Ruqaiya and a communist party luminary named Izzat Jahan. At different points in the story, Ruqaiya and Izzat Jahan each has occasion to call someone else rude, hence the title. But I'm unable to track down the story in question on Rekhta. The most obvious Urdu translation for "rude" would be *bad_tamiiz*, ill-mannered, but [the story called *bad_tamiizii*](https://www.rekhta.org/ghazals/badtamizi-saadat-hasan-manto-stories?lang=hi) ("Rudeness") is a different one altogether. None of the other titles on the Rekhta page seem to be translatable as "Rude," so I don't know which story this is. **What is the Urdu original of "Rude,"** and is it available online, preferably in Devanagari script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manto does in fact have a story called *bad_tamiiz*, بدتمیز . This is the story translated as "Rude" in *Bombay Stories*, and it is indeed different from the story called *bad_tamiizii*, بدتمیزی , which would be "Rudeness."

*bad_tamiiz* بدتمیز has not been transcribed or transliterated on rekhta.org, but the friend who identified the story for me pointed to the digitized version there of Manto's [*Namrood ki Khudai*,  نمرود کی خدائی](https://www.rekhta.org/ebooks/namrood-ki-khudai-saadat-hasan-manto-ebooks) , *The Divinity of Nimrod*. This collection has the story beginning on page 64.

Here is [Jameel Gulrays reading the story out loud in Urdu on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QUQR5kYQdlU). The story proper begins at the 0:30 mark. And here is a screenshot of the first page, complete with Rekhta watermark:

[image: First page of Manto's story "bad_tamiiz". Screenshot of copy on rekhta.org]